# Does Excel have Sticky headers that you can freeze the pane like in Bootstrap?

Tags: microsoft-excel, headers

I have a spreadsheet where there are multiple headers and they are like a million lines up the spreadsheet, so when I want to see what category it is in, I have to scroll up for like a million years... it's not a sheet of my own making either, I inherited it.

Is it possible to do something like what they do in mobile apps ([example1](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/listview/sticky-header)) and bootstrap ([example2](https://bootstrap-menu.com/demos/fixed-onscroll.html), [example3](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/sticky-header.html); scroll down, of course), and make it so the header is sticky until it gets to the next header, or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: Have you tried Freeze Panes?   That works for me.

Comment: @John Freeze Panes only work for a single header, not multiple headers of multiple tables

Comment: Freeze pane works both vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @John obviously you can freeze both vertical and horizontal panes but how on earth is that related to support multiple tables in **multiple rows (or columns)** like the OP want? Did you even see my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. In the Home tab just select *Styles > Format as Table* and when the cursor is inside the table the header will be "sticky" unlike Freeze panes where the whole row is frozen permanently

[image: Excel Format as table]

Demo:

[image: Sticky header]

[image]